# How can I increase a cell reference automatically in Excel VBA so that a macro is run in every column?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, reference, cell

So I have a macro that references specific cells in a workbook. How can I repeat this macro in the next fifty columns without manually typing out the cell references fifty times?

If I was just using excel formulas and not VBA I could click and drag to automatically repeat the formulas in the next column. The cell references I would like to remain the same I would define as $absolute$ references. But in VBA I don't know how to do it.

Here is the code:

```
If Worksheets("Enter Data Here").Range("D11") = "" Then
    Worksheets("SDS").Range("R5") = Worksheets("SDS").Range("R5") & ""

ElseIf Worksheets("Enter Data Here").Range("D11") = "/" Then
    Worksheets("SDS").Range("R5") = Worksheets("SDS").Range("R5") & ";" & Worksheets("Enter Data Here").Range("D10")

ElseIf Worksheets("Enter Data Here").Range("D11") = "//" Then
    Worksheets("SDS").Range("R5") = Worksheets("SDS").Range("R5") & ";" & Worksheets("Enter Data Here").Range("D10") & "x2"

ElseIf Worksheets("Enter Data Here").Range("D11") = "///" Then
    Worksheets("SDS").Range("R5") = Worksheets("SDS").Range("R5") & ";" & Worksheets("Enter Data Here").Range("D10") & "x3"


End If
```

Worksheets("SDS").Range("R5") is the absolute cell reference and does not change, but I would like the others to shift along to the next column without typing it. e.g. D becomes E, then F.

There must be a labour saving way of doing this. Maybe looping?

Cheers.

Comment: `Offset`, or use `Cells` instead of `Range` and loop incrementing the column.

Comment: Are you also adding another "/" each time?

Comment: No, a "/" means a test is scheduled, and therefore the name of the test (D10) needs to be plotted in R5. There are only up to three tests, so never more than 3 x ///.

Comment: So you have four clauses for D and then 4 for E etc?

Comment: Yep! Literally just needs to shift to the cell to the right. D11 becomes E11 etc and D10 becomes E10...

Comment: And how do you tell when to end - is it a fixed number of iterations? Clearly you can't stop just because the cell in row 10 is empty.

Comment: Good point. It needs to go along for 50 columns, so it would end at AZ11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
Sub x()

Dim r1 As Range, i As Long

Set r1 = Worksheets("Enter Data Here").Range("D11") 'define starting cell

For i = 1 To 50 'repeat this 50 times
    With Worksheets("SDS").Range("R5")
        If r1 = "" Then
             .Value = .Value & "" 'not sure what purpose this serves
        ElseIf r1.Value = "/" Then
            .Value = .Value & ";" & r1.Offset(-1).Value
        ElseIf r1.Value = "//" Then
            .Value = .Value & ";" & r1.Offset(-1).Value & "x2"
        ElseIf r1.Value = "///" Then
            .Value = .Value & ";" & r1.Offset(-1).Value & "x3"
        End If
    End With
    Set r1 = r1.Offset(, 1) 'move to cell to the right, E11, F11 etc
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This is spot on and works perfectly, thanks so much. This would be a loop? Seeing it like this actually makes me understand how they work! Cheers!

Comment: you should have `With Worksheets("SDS").Range("R5")` enclose `For i` loop

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me you should be after this:

```
Dim cel As Range
Dim s As String
For Each cel In Worksheets("Enter Data Here").Range("D11").Resize(, 50)
    Select Case Len(r1) - Len(Replace(r1, "/", vbNullString))
        Case 1
            s = s & ";" & cel.Offset(-1).Value
        Case 2
            s = s & ";" & cel.Offset(-1).Value & "x2"
        Case 3
            s = s & ";" & cel.Offset(-1).Value & "x3"
        End If
    End Select
End With

Worksheets("SDS").Range("R5").Value = s
```